# How to align the BPMN models with the Technology Architecture?

Tags: business-process-management, bpmn, rup, togaf

I stuck how to proceed further and need some new ideas to align these BPMN models which I have drawn for Customer Relationship Management(CRM) and Human Resources(HR).

As far as BPM model is considered it's mainly used for Business Architecture(BA) and then for Technical Architecture(TA) I could possibly use Rational Unified Process(RUP) but when I researched I could only find IBM Rational Rose Software which is not free...

My Question:-

1. Is there, open Source RUP tools which I can use? I looked up OpenUp but I could not make it work(which is a different issue).
2. Is this the right approach; for BA -> BPM and TA -> RUP ?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is much too broad and unspecific to be answered here. First, RUP is part of IBM's product palette and therefore most probably not available anywhere else. More important, RUP is  a process for software modeling, so you won't be happy with it describing CRM or HR problems. For the rest of your questions, we would need to know much more about your present models *and the specific troubles you have with them* to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of BPMN ([BPMN specification 1. Scope](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/) ) describes

> The primary goal of BPMN is to provide a notation that is readily understandable by all business users, **from the business
>   analysts that create the initial drafts of the processes, to the technical developers responsible for implementing the
>   technology that will perform those processes, and finally, to the business people who will manage and monitor those
>   processes**. Thus, BPMN creates a standardized bridge for the gap between the business process design and process
>   implementation.

There are Business process management(BPM) software's which provides process modeling and process execution conformance. Thus effectively making the models executable [**at least to a certain depth**].

In the free/ open source world you can find [jBPM](http://www.jbpm.org/), [Activiti](http://activiti.org/) etc...

I have tried out jBPM, is pretty much mature and has standard notations compliance. Also it supports modeling, execution and operational functionalities.